# *ngFor - not able to render items dynamically - Angular 6 - Mat-menu button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

So far am having,

```
  this.ItemList = [{
    "item1":"value-1".
    "item2":"value-2".
    "item3":"value-3".
    "item4":"value-4".
    }];

<button mat-button mat-raised-button color="warn" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (click)='dummyBtn($event)'>List of values</button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" *ngFor = "let list of ItemList">
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    /*<button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>*/
  </mat-menu>
```

I don't see any errors in the console. but at the same time values not getting rendered, instead, it's just showing hardcoded values.

could some tell me how to achieve this? the existing stackblitz example seems to be complicating to generate dynamic element. or is that really not possible with my approach?

**pls, do not downvote without any reasons. I've come across few examples, those are not helping as of now**
thank you

Comment: In ItemList you have `.` instead of `,`

Comment: Weird you're not getting any errors in the console given that you have syntax errors in the typescript code

Comment: Your ItemList contains only one object. You may need to iterate the key values of that object.

Comment: lols.. i just typed by myself just to show here as sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare `objectKeys = Object.keys` in ts file and in html,

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(ItemList[0])">
    {{ ItemList[0][key] }}
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: this is also another way. Great!

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try this and let me know the results?

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" *ngFor = "let list of ItemList">
<button mat-menu-item>{{list}}</button>
/*<button mat-menu-item>{{list}}</button>
<button mat-menu-item>{{list}}</button>*/
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: `list` is an object too, and you want a string inside the button body. I'm not sure what the idea is behind OP's `ItemList` structure, but it should probably be {{list.item1}}

Comment: {{list.item1}} will only display single value, to iterate through all of them, {{list}} is to be used.

Comment: @sid `<button>` expects a string inside of it, not an object which is what you give it. Notice that ItemList is a list of objects, so list will be an object which is not iterable. What I meant was that OP probably wants to create multiple buttons in each iteration, like `<button>{{list.item1}}</button> <button>{{list.item2}}</button>...`.

Answer (score 1):

Feeling worst. I just did a dead silly mistake,

1. declaring a variable inside a function, so the scope of 'let abc' is not alive out of function.
2. var which was declared is not an array

I just correct the above mistakes. now working as expected